# Understanding Java Interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

So I looked online through a number of resources to understand Java interfaces. I believe I have a good general understanding of them but when programming them I am a bit confused...

I created an interface called A and have the following inside...

```
    public interface A {
    public int sum(int first, int second);
}
```

I then created a class called B.

```
public class B implements A {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int result = sum(3, 5);
    }

    public int sum(int first, int second) {
        int total = first + second;
        return total;
    }

}
```

Now what I am trying to figure out is how can I properly call / use the method "sum". In Eclipse I'm getting an error for the line "int result = sum(3, 5);" and it is telling me to make the method static. If I make it static, then the method needs to match it in the interface. However, I am not able to use static methods in an interface?

Any help is appreciated and thank you for your time to read about my problems.

Comment: It is not the best example: sum is fundamentally static...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you have is not of interface but of `static` method.

`main` is a `static` method. That means it is not linked to an object/instance, but to the class itself.

Since you want to use `sum`, which is an instance method, you need first to create an object to call its method.

```
A a = new B();
int result = a.sum(5, 6);
```

Usually, instance methods are more linked to the object status, while static methods are more like "procedures" in non OO languages. In the case of `sum`, your method would make more sense as static. But, if you use `B` to wrap a value (status), and use sum to add to your internal status, this would end (in a more OO friendly way).

```
A a = new B(5);
a.sum(6);
int result = a.getValue();
```

Note that both approachs are valid and both compile in Java, it is just a matter of selecting the modifiers that make more sense in each occasion.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `sum()` from your main method because sum is an instance method, not static. It needs to be called from an instance of a class.

You need to instantiate your class:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    B b = new B();
    int result = b.sum(3, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class B implements A {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int result = new B.sum(3, 5); 
        // Create an instance of B so you can access 
        // the non-static method from a static reference
        // Or if you want to see the power of the interface...
        A a = new B();
        int result = a.sum(3, 5); 
    }

    public int sum(int first, int second) {
        int total = first + second;
        return total;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By creating an instance of B like this:

```
A a =  new B();
    int result = a.sum(3, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the issue of static, not interface. You can not call non-static method from static method. You can call sum method by creating its object.

like,

```
int result = new B.sum(3, 5);
```

inside static method.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to make this clear by giving another example:

Make a classed named Animal.

```
public interface Animal {
  String speak();
}
```

Now make a class named Cat

```
public class Cat implements Animal {
  public String speak() {
    return "meow"
  }
}
```

And a class named Dog

```
public class Dog implements Animal {
  public String speak() {
    return "woof"
  }
}
```

Now you can do this

```
public String speak(Animal a) {
  System.out.printf("%s\n", a.speak());
}

Cat cat = new Animal();
Dog dog = new Animal();
speak(cat); //prints meow
speak(dog); //prints woof
```

That means `Cat` is an `Animal` and `Dog` is is an `Animal` too, so you can pass a `Cat` or `Dog` object to a function that takes `Animal` arguments.

It's like Inheritance, but since in Java a class can only inherit from one other class, you can use Interfaces to get around that. You only declare methods in the Interface; you have to define them in the class that implements it.

It can also be used for things like `ActionListeners` or `MouseListeners`. You can have a GUI class that implements it, then have a function that handles all of your `ActionEvents` like button clicking and mouse clicking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be very simple , either make your sum method static or create an instance of class B and use it to call the sum method:

```
B b=new B();
int result=b.sum(3,5);
```

or

just write static before your sum method

for eg:

```
 public static  int sum(int first, int second)

 {

     int total = first + second;
     return total;

 }
```